# How to change the username in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, users, settings, system-settings, username

I need to change the username from the linux (Not admin).

I changed in settings ->Users. But how to change the "home folder" name or root user in linux.

I tried using

```
usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>
```

But this always mentions that

```
username <oldname> is currently used by process <some id>
```

Does anything happen if I kill the process?

I logged in as root using `su -` and tried the same `usermod` command.

So, how do I change the name without killing the process?

Any leads will be appreciated. I have attached a screenshot of changed username in **Settings > Users**.

[image: Sunag "your user" and Admin]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change username and home directory name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815208/change-username-and-home-directory-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General method that I use:

- Create new user

  ```
  useradd {newuser}
  passwd {newuser}
  ```
- Move personal files over from old user to new user

  ```
  sudo cp -r /home/{olduser}/[A-Z]* /home/{newuser}/
  ```
- `chown` personal files to new user if needed

  ```
  sudo chown -R {newuser}:{newuser} /home/{newuser}/[A-Z]*
  ```
- Log in to new user and delete old user after you confirm new user is working as intended (that makes sure no process are active for olduser).

  ```
  userdel {olduser}
  ```
- do not copy/paste and do adjust the commands to what you need :)

Comment: I followed this [article](https://studiesonline.in/how-to-change-username-in-ubuntu-18-04-20-04/), and it seemed to work well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are logged in as the user which you are trying to modify.  When you execute the su -  command, the original login is still active which is why you see the error.  If you attempt to kill the process, you will be killing the  session which you are using and will be disconnected!

You need to log out of the system and then log in as root (or another user with enough privileges). This will enable you to perform the changes.  (Note: just Switching user will not work because the other user will still be active)