# How to fix unconnected User?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I am using WSL, and I recently found the path to my Ubuntu files in Windows. I renamed my user's home folder through Windows, and now I see the following:

```
This message is shown once a day.
To disable it please create the 
/home/useradd/.hushlogin file.
touch: cannot touch '/home/userad/.motd_shown':
Permission denied
-bash: /home/useradd/.bash_profile: 
Permission denied
```

I don't really know what to do and how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to All Ubuntu!  Are you saying that you changed the name of your Ubuntu user's home folder using File Explorer in Windows?

Comment: Well i changed the name of the folder and now it's telling me i should create the /home/useradd/ .hushlogin file., aswell as touch: cannot touch '/home/useradd/.motd_shown': Permission denied                                                      -bash: /home/useradd/.bash_profile: Permission denied     and i

Comment: So i followed the path to where the files where saved and renamed the folder of my username to another one thats what i did and then those things occured.

Comment: DO NOT alter the WSL files via Windows!  You WILL break your WSL

Answer (score 1):

> I recently found the path to my Ubuntu files in Windows. I renamed my user's home folder through Windows

Let's start with, *don't do that!* ;-)

While the normal WSL permissions *shouldn't* allow you to do that in the first place, apparently you were able to somehow.  I'm not sure how, but it doesn't really matter.  Simply renaming a Linux user's home folder will *never* work, even in "normal" (non-WSL) Ubuntu.  For that matter, renaming your Windows user's folder would have a similar (perhaps worse) effect.

While I can't rename my user's home directory through Windows, I can still reproduce your same error by starting Ubuntu as root with:

```
wsl ~ -d Ubuntu -u root
```

Then:

```
mv /home/ntd /home/xyz
```

After that, when I attempt to login as my ntd user, yes, I see that message.

The problem is that Ubuntu still thinks the home directory for my user is `/home/ntd` (and for yours, `/home/useradd` apparently).  For instance:

```
# echo $HOME
/home/ntd
# cd ~
-bash: cd: /home/ntd: No such file or directory
```

Also, certain items in the *default* startup files reference `$HOME`.  For instance, in `/etc/profile.d/update-motd.sh` you'll find:

```
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] && [ -z "$MOTD_SHOWN" ] && ! find $stamp -newermt 'today 0:00' 2> /dev/null | grep -q -m 1 '.'; then
                [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] || SHOW="--show-only"
                update-motd $SHOW
                echo ""
                eval_gettext "This message is shown once a day. To disable it please create the"
                echo -n "$HOME/.hushlogin "
...
```

> I don't really know what to do and how to fix it.

At this point, the easiest way to fix that particular issue is to tell Ubuntu where the user's *new* home directory is.  You can do this by:

- Exiting Ubuntu
- Start PowerShell and:

  ```
  wsl ~ -u root
  ```
- This starts Ubuntu as the root user.  Then start the "safe editor" for the passwd file with:

  ```
  vipw
  ```
- Look for the line that starts with your normal username (which sounds like it is `useradd`).  It will probably look something like:

  ```
  useradd:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/useradd:/bin/bash
  ```
- Change the `/home/useradd` to the new directory name.
- Save and exit

Exit Ubuntu and restart it as your normal user.  Hopefully, the error will be fixed.

---

Note that the proper way to change the directory name is (as mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/815208/1165986)) to use `usermod -d`.  This is quite a bit easier in WSL than normal, since you can easily start as root and make sure that your normal user isn't in use.

- Exit Ubuntu and from PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl -l -v
  # Confirm the name of the distribution being used
  # and replace "Ubuntu" below with the correct name if 
  # it is different

  wsl --terminate Ubuntu
  wsl ~ -u root
  ```
- In Ubuntu:

  ```
  usermod -d /home/<new_directory> -m <username>
  ```

The `-d` specifies the new directory, and the `-m` specifies that the existing user files should be moved to that directory.